# Почему в Fancybox выводится фотографий большее количество, чем изначально загружено?

Tags: html, css, fancybox

Почему при выводе фотографий крупным планом показывается фотографий больше, чем я загружал? У меня загружено изначально 6 изображений, а он выводит 14. Как сделать так, чтобы выводилось столько, сколько загружено?

сам сайт http://tempeswo.beget.tech/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    
    
    $(".services .wrapper.owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        nav: true,
        navText : ["<i class='fas fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fas fa-chevron-right'></i>"],
        dots: false,
        autoplay:true,
        center: false,
        loop:true,
        margin:40,
        responsiveClass:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1,
                margin:20
            },
            370:{
                items:2,
                margin:20
            },
            800:{
                items:3
            },
            1000:{
                items:4
            }
        }
    });

    $('.photos .gallery.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                autoplayHoverPause: true,
                nav: true,
                navText :true,
                dots: true,
                autoplay:true,
                center: true,
                loop:true,
                margin:10,
                responsiveClass:true,
                responsive:{
                    0:{
                        items:1,
                        margin:20
                    },
                    370:{
                        items:2,
                        margin:20
                    },
                    800:{
                        items:3
                    },
                    1000:{
                        items:4
                    }
                }
    })

   
});
```

```css
html, body {
    font-size:14px;
    color:#202020;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.8;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 1000px;
    padding: 30px 60px 30px 60px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

section {
    padding: 90px 0 !important;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Section main */

.main {
    padding: 0 !important;
    color: #fff;
}


.intro {
   position: relative;
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../img/video-bg.jpg) top no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}


.intro:after {
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    z-index: 2;
}

.video {
    
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.video_media {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    z-index: 4;
}


.logo h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
}

.logo span {
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
}

/* Section about */

.about .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.photo {
    padding-right: 60px;
    width: 40%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.info {
    width: 60%;
    position: relative;
}

.photo img {
   width: 100%;
   border-radius: 100%;
}

.info p {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.info p:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea; 
}

.lips {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    right: 0;
    width: 180px;
}

/* Section photos */


.gallery .owl-nav {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
}

.owl-dots {
    padding-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.owl-dot {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.owl-dot.active {
    background-color: #f7971d;
}

/* Section services */

.services {
    background-color: #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.services .wrapper {
    max-width: 1400px;
}

.services .item {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.services .item img {
    width: 200px !important;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.services .item h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 30px -10px 23px 0 !important;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.services .item p {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.services .owl-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.services .owl-nav div {
    width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.services .item .button {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
    opacity: 0.15;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.services .item:hover .button {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
}

.services .owl-stage-outer:hover .owl-item {
    opacity: 0.65;
}

.services .owl-item {
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.services .owl-stage-outer .owl-item:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="keywords" content="" />

<meta name="description" content="" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8e0bceeac7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/clear.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/adaptive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="css/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<title>KATYA LEER</title>

<link href="img/lips.svg" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,300,400,500,700,800,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
   <section class="main">
    <div class="intro">
        <div class="video">
            <video src="video.mp4" class="video_media" autoplay muted loop></video>
        </div>
          <div class="logo">
              <h1>KATYA LEER</h1>
              <span>makeup</span>

         </div>
    </div>
    
    
   </section>
    
    <section class="about">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="photo">
              <img src="img/katyaleer.jpg">
          </div>
            <div class="info">
                <p>Привет! Я Катя, и я делаю красивый образ без тонны косметики и лака.</p>

                <p>Тебе не придется ломать голову над тем, какой выбрать макияж и прическу – доверь это мне! Я предложу тебе варианты, которые будут максимально подходить твоему лицу, характеру и стилю.</p>

                <p>А если ты устала часами выбирать себе нужный оттенок тонального, тратить деньги на ненужную косметику, то приходи ко мне на курс «Макияж для себя».</p>

                <p>Более подробно ознакомиться с моими<br/>услугами и ценами можно ниже.</p>

                <p>Katya Leer</p>
                
                <img class="lips" src="img/lips.svg">
            </div>
            
         </div>
    </section> 

    

    <section class="photos">
       <div class="gallery owl-carousel">
        <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="photos/big/1.jpg">
          <img src="photos/min/1.jpg" >
        </a>
          
        <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="photos/big/2.jpg">
          <img src="photos/min/2.jpg" >
        </a>
        
        <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="photos/big/3.jpg">
          <img src="photos/min/3.jpg" >
        </a>
          
        <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="photos/big/4.jpg">
          <img src="photos/min/4.jpg" >
        </a>
          
        <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="photos/big/5.jpg">
          <img src="photos/min/5.jpg" >
        </a>
          
        <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="photos/big/6.jpg">
          <img src="photos/min/6.jpg" >
        </a>
              
   </section> 
    
    <section class="services">
        
        <div class="wrapper owl-carousel">
               
            <a data-fancybox data-src="#test" href="javascript:;" class="item">
                <img src="photos/min/1.jpg">
                <h2>Маникюр</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <div class="button">
                    Подробнее
                </div>
            </a>
            
            <a data-fancybox data-src="#test" href="javascript:;" class="item">
                <img src="photos/min/1.jpg">
                <h2>Покраска</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <div class="button">
                    Подробнее
                </div>
            </a>
            
            <a data-fancybox data-src="#test" href="javascript:;" class="item">
                <img src="photos/min/1.jpg">
                <h2>Ботокс</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <div class="button">
                    Подробнее
                </div>
            </a>
            
            <a data-fancybox data-src="#test" href="javascript:;" class="item">
                <img src="photos/min/1.jpg">
                <h2>Татуаж</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <div class="button">
                    Подробнее
                </div>
            </a>
            
            <a data-fancybox data-src="#test" href="javascript:;" class="item">
                <img src="photos/min/1.jpg">
                <h2>Стрижка</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <div class="button">
                    Подробнее
                </div>
            </a>
           
         
        </div>
        
    </section> 
    
    
<div class="hidden">  
    
<div id="test">
hello
</div>
    
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```